# Copy cell values (not cell formula)

Tags: excel, vba

I just need help to get this right.
When i copy the macro copy all ( including formulas ) and what i want is just to copy the values.
Can any one help?

```
Sub Gerar()

    Range("B28:AR29").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("testettt").Select
    Range("B22:AR23").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Dados Pessoais + Exper. Prof").Select
    Range("A3").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try this:

```
Range("B28:AR29").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("testettt").Select
Range("B22:AR23").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly copy and paste the range from one sheet to other, check the below code:

```
Sub try()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B15:B25").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B15:B25").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This above code is only for copy paste, you remaining code is not included in this.